# Error when accessing a Library in Site Content and Structure

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-and-structure

Please I get an "Unexpected Error" when trying to access a library from the Site Content and Structure.

I am able to access the library from "View All Site Content".

How do I resolve the issue of accessing it from "Site Content and Structure".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Access other library from the site content and structure to check if the same issue will occur.
2. Create a new library and access the library from site content and structure to check if the same issue will occur.

And if the issue just occurs in one library, I suggest you could move the content from the problematic library to the normal library.